# Selenium search bar is not showing any suggestions

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I am currently working on a project that would make trading stocks automatic. After Logging In on the trading website, the idea is for selenium to insert the keys: "FB" into the search bar. If you do this manual suggestion for the stocks you are looking for pops up. But to my surprise, they do not show as soon as selenium takes control. I will give away the full code if anyone wants to try the program themself, just change the path to the browser! The account is fake, so don't worry... :)

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/larskvist/downloads/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.forex.com/en-uk/account-login/')

username_elem = browser.find_element_by_name('Username')
username_elem.send_keys('kebababdulaziz@gmail.com')

password_elem = browser.find_element_by_name('Password')
password_elem.send_keys('KEbababdulaziz')
password_elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

search_elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.market-search__search-input")))
search_elem.send_keys('FB')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you identify the element first click on the element and then provide send_keys()

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/larskvist/downloads/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.forex.com/en-uk/account-login/')
username_elem = browser.find_element_by_name('Username')
username_elem.send_keys('kebababdulaziz@gmail.com')
password_elem = browser.find_element_by_name('Password')
password_elem.send_keys('KEbababdulaziz')
password_elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

search_elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.market-search__search-input")))
search_elem.click()
search_elem.send_keys('FB')
```

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, extremely helpfull! I guess i makes sense that the search results only show, when you've clicked it... Any recommendations on how to get this knowledge on Selenium?

Comment: @LarsKvist : What I did just manually check when i click on input field its open up the pop up so I follow the same step in selenium.Click first and then enter data in input field.While automating we should always follow user experience with different trials.

Comment: Copy that master!

Answer (score 2):

You need to click on this input after typing "FB":

```
...
search_elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.market-search__search-input")))
search_elem.send_keys("FB")
time.sleep(5)
search_elem.click()
```

I hope it helps you!